# Lightning Compiler - what happens when we save a lightning bundle

Tags: lightning, compile

Does the lightning bundle elements (html/xml, css, js) gets stored in salesforce servers in their individual native formats and served back to clients in the same format per request ?

OR

is there any other steps / process happening on the salesforce server side ?

I've seen some notes on the lightning docs that SF uses [Google Closure](https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/) to compile the lightning JS files but no other info beyond that..

It will be interesting to understand what happens when we create / save a lightning bundle

Answer (score 3):

Here is the info i gathered from one of the [session](https://www.slideshare.net/developerforce/mastering-the-lightning-framework-part-1)

1.The Server creates Java objects from component XML

2.Components are Serialized to JSON

3.The client creates JS component instances

4.The JS components create DOM elements

XML---> JAVA--> JSON--->JS--->DOM

So to answer you everything is stored as XML to begin with .There is not visibility to what happens under the hood .